# Unity. What does joint angular limits mean?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to limit target rotation of `ConfigurableJoint` to avoid distortion or destruction of joint.

To see how angular limits work I have made an experiment.

1. Place a humanoid model on the scene.
2. Add `ConfigurableJoint` to a bone;
3. Add script to control `targetRotation` property by the Euler angles.

   ```
   using UnityEngine;

   public class TestLimits : MonoBehaviour
   {
       [Range(-120, 120)]
       public float x;
       [Range(-120, 120)]
       public float y;
       [Range(-120, 120)]
       public float z;
       public Vector3 currentTorque; // to indicate limits

       private ConfigurableJoint j;

       void Start()
       {
           j = GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
       }

       void Update()
       {
           j.targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z);
           currentTorque = j.currentTorque;
       }
   }
   ```

Changing the `targetRotation` we can see the limitation of joint's motion.

As expected, limitation is observed when the angles reach limit values. But not always. It happens only when other two angles equal to zero. For example, if
 x = 91 and y = 89, observed z-limits changes in the direction of increase.

What does it mean?
How can I limit target rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer in Phisx [documentation.](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/Joints.html#spherical-joint)

> The spherical joint supports a cone limit, which constrains the angle between the X-axes of the two constraint frames. Actor1's X-axis is constrained by a limit cone whose axis is the x-axis of actor0's constraint frame. The allowed limit values are the maximum rotation around the y- and z- axes of that frame. Different values for the y- and z- axes may be specified, in which case the limit takes the form of an elliptical angular cone.

1. Both y and z axes are axes of Actor0. So we can not use Euler angles.
2. Limit is elliptical angular cone. So y and z angles are conctrained by inequality y<sup>2</sup>/a<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup>/b<sup>2</sup> < 1. Here a and b are limits.
3. It appears then that the angular cone rotates relative to actor0 around the twist axis.

This function limits rotation exactly to joints limits.

```
private Quaternion targetRotation(ConfigurableJoint j, float x, float y, float z)
{
    // twist
    float angle = x;
    Vector3 axis = Vector3.right;

    if (angle > j.highAngularXLimit.limit)
        angle = j.highAngularXLimit.limit;
    if (angle < j.lowAngularXLimit.limit)
        angle = j.lowAngularXLimit.limit;
    Quaternion twist = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);

    // swing
    angle = Mathf.Sqrt(y * y + z * z);
    axis = new Vector3(0, y, z);

    Vector3 t = twist * axis;
    float a = t.y / j.angularYLimit.limit;
    float b = t.z / j.angularZLimit.limit;
    float l = a * a + b * b;
    if (l > 1)
        angle = angle / Mathf.Sqrt(l);

    Quaternion swing = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);

    return twist * swing;
}
```